# Google Analytics: Spreadsheet Add-on invalid value 'daysAgo'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-sheets

I'm trying to do build an automatic report query with the Google Analytics spreadsheet add-on. I want to get a monthly report (start of month to end of month) about users, visits etc. According to the Google Analytics documentation, it's possible to set a startDate and endDate in the following format:

*Values must match [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}|today|yesterday|[0-9]+(daysAgo).*

However i'm getting an error which looks like this:

[Report failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrCPa.png)

My settings looks like this:

[Settings in Google Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quINx.png)

Does anybody know what causes my error? This feature will be really handy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values you are passing?

Comment: startDate is: 2015-12-01. endDate is: 2015-12-31. I also tried with relative dates fx: startDate: yesterday. endDate: today, which also doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

First you have to schedule your report every month and then you can use the function eomonth() to calculate start and end dates.

Start date -> = EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2) +1

End date -> = EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it on a different profile or a larger date range. I was able to get data using the exact query that you shared. You can also try the [Google Analytics Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/)and see if that gives you works or it gives you more detailed error information.